Express-session session undefined (express on localhost:3000 client on liveserver)
I am running the server no localhost:3000 and the client on liveserver (127.0.0.1:5500).
When i login it creates a express-session (it returns session created successfully) but when i try to access it on the client it says undefined. But if i run everything on localhost:3000 then the session works. How do i create the session and or cookie on 127.0.0.1 so the user can lets say move forum.html and post a comment trough res.session.user.id.
I have tried changing it to use cookies didnt work created it on the server.
Tried various cookie and session settings which did not work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
